# Snowflake dynamic procedure statement.Execute() return value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I have a snowflake procedure using javascript.
the procedure exec the statement and return a single value result into a var:
var res = stmt.execute();
I want insert this value into a table. but this value is return as an object.
How do I work around the solution?

My script is dynamic and has a while loop that generates multiple statements, but here is a simplified version to focus on what I need to do get
Thx

create Procedure GetLastUpdateDate()
returns boolean
language javascript
as
$$

```
sql_command = "select max(Updatedate) from MyTable;";

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_command});
var res = stmt.execute();
 
    snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE (NCOLUMN) VALUES (?)',   
                                    binds: [res]
                                } ).execute();    
                     
$$
;
```

Answer (score 1):

[.getColumnValue()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#id4) could be used:

> getColumnValue(colIdx|colName)
>
> This method returns the value of a column in the current row (i.e. the row most recently retrieved by next()).

```
sql_command = "select max(Updatedate) from MyTable;";

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_command});
var res = stmt.execute();

while (res.next()) {
 var myVal = res.getColumnValue(1);

 snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE (NCOLUMN) VALUES (?)',   
                             binds: [myVal]
                             } ).execute();   
}
```

If more than one row is expected loop should be used: `while (res.next()) {...}`

Comment: Adding to Lukasz's answer... "If more than one row is expected loop should be used: while (res.next()) {...}" -- In the loop, don't insert one row at a time. Construct a values clause and batch them to 10k rows or however many will fit into a 1 MB statement.

Comment: @GregPavlik Yes, that's very important note. By more than one row I was thinking about a few iterations. If more then bulk operations perform much better.

Comment: Statement.Execute () sample bellow 
       var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_command});
       var res = stmt.execute();
always return an object ( 2 dimensions - rows vs colomns) even a scalar value.  Therefore, it need to access the ojbect:
 while (res.next()) 
     { var    myVal = res.getColumnValue(1);
     }